# ionic 2 popup handler function not updating variable

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to update variable on "OK" click of pop-up, but some how I am not able to update variable. In console it shows updated value whereas it is not updating in view.

```
this.barcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => {
            let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
              title: 'Barcode scanned Successfully!',
              subTitle: ''+barcodeData.text,
              buttons: [{
                text: 'OK',
                handler: () => {
                    this.showForm = true;
                    this.memberVo["barcodeId"] = barcodeData.text;
                }
              }]
            });
            alert.present();
        }, (err) => {
            // An error occurred
            console.log('barcode err--',err);
            let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
              title: 'Barcode scan Failed!',
              subTitle: ''+err,
              buttons: ['OK']
            });
            alert.present();
        });
```

Here `this.showForm = true;` variable is not updating in view/html

Answer (score 0):

you need notify Angular Change Detection update view, using `NgZone` or `ChangeDetectorRef`

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}
```

then do something like this

```
this.zone.run(() => {
    this.barcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => {
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'Barcode scanned Successfully!',
          subTitle: ''+barcodeData.text,
          buttons: [{
            text: 'OK',
            handler: () => {
                this.showForm = true;
                this.memberVo["barcodeId"] = barcodeData.text;
            }
          }]
        });
        alert.present();
    }, (err) => {
        // An error occurred
        console.log('barcode err--',err);
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'Barcode scan Failed!',
          subTitle: ''+err,
          buttons: ['OK']
        });
        alert.present();
    });
});
```

or using `ChangeDetectorRef`

```
constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

then

```
this.barcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Barcode scanned Successfully!',
      subTitle: ''+barcodeData.text,
      buttons: [{
        text: 'OK',
        handler: () => {
            this.showForm = true;
            this.memberVo["barcodeId"] = barcodeData.text;
            this.cdRef.detectChanges(); // this one
        }
      }]
    });
    alert.present();
}, (err) => {
    // An error occurred
    console.log('barcode err--',err);
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Barcode scan Failed!',
      subTitle: ''+err,
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present();
});
```

Documentation:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgZone-class.html

Comment: Thank you for pointing at zone.run. This actually didn't worked for me (very similar problem, but with async functions). Moving zone.run inside the handler (wrapping the handler code) did the job.
I'm using ionic 4 with angular 6